# C# EF context how to take just specific tables from SQL database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've many databases with the same structure of tables (various data) e.g. city, country, area.

I would like to consolidate into one database and create a table name prefix to identify the database they have come from. Thus obtained database contains the same tables with different code.

How to create a C# Entity Framework context through the code takes only tables with a certain prefix now I want to connect to? In the context table names will be without prefix

Example:

Tables in Sample database a1:

- Country
- City
- Area

Tables in Sample database b1:

- Country
- City
- Area

Now, after consolidation in merged database the tables will become:

- a1_city
- b1_city
- a1_country
- b1_country
- a1_area
- b1_area

Will be an option to take only tables with prefix `a1` and called city, country

Is there any change in the connection string and how? Or somewhere else?

Comment: please share what have u done so far question is not detaled plz add more details to work on

Comment: If I understood you correctly - you have got several databases e.g. a1, b1 etc and you've consolidated their tables in one database. Now through EF context you want to load the tables which have come only from a specific database e.g a1_city, a1_country, a1_area. You don't want to load tables coming from other database when you initialize your EF context. Is it?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant

Comment: How do you decide that you would want to load the tables prefixed with specific code e.g. a1? Would you configure it in your app.config file?

Comment: please see if [this](http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2010/12/05/changing-entity-framework-model-at-runtime/) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035238/dynamic-table-name-with-entity-framework) helps you. But this isn't an easy and straight forward thing in EF. You want to dynamically change loaded tables at run time.

Comment: Every time you create a context
using (WLContext context = new WLContext (this.connectionString))

Take only the tables with the prefix you just have to
For example:
If
prefix = a1
So
Context.city = A1_city
Context.country = A1_country
Or
prefix = b1
So
Context.city = B1_city
Context.country = B1_country