# Build a generic WebAPI that can consume Table name as a parameter and return Data from table that is passed as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httprequest, httpresponse

I am new to web API,I want to build an API,that can consume Table name as a parameter and return data of the table which is passed as parameter name at runtime.How can we achieve this using c#?

I have entity data model configured for my database,Unable to figure out how to develop a generic API which will return table data depending on table name sent as parameter

```
 // GET: api/PickLists
        public IQueryable<PickList> GetPickLists()
        {
            return db.PickLists;
        }
```

Above code returns me data of the table mentioned,How can i make it generic to return table depending on parameter name(Which contains Name of Database tabel)

Comment: Just get the table using entity framework and return the query as json? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I am able to return it for a single table.However I am confused how do i do it for Multiple tables depeding on parameter.This might be something silly but I am totally new to c# and webapi

Comment: You could create a factory that returns the correct DBContext Instance for a parameter. How to use WebAPI + EF see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic table name with entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035238/dynamic-table-name-with-entity-framework)

Comment: IQueryable is not data, it's just an expression that hasn't run yet, so do not ever return that from an API. ALWAYS make sure you run the query by doing a ToList() for example.

Comment: @sejal did it help?

Comment: somehow that did not work for me.But it did add to my knowledge :).Thank for your suggestion. I figured out some other method to get that working

Answer (score 0):

You could use the factory pattern to retrieve the db context you need given a specified parameter:

```
public class DbContextFactory {

    private readonly TodoContext todoContext;
    private readonly OtherContext otherContext;

    // Uses dependency injection
    public DbContextFactory(TodoContext todoContext, OtherContext otherContext) {
        this.todoContext = todoContext;
        this.otherContext = otherContext;
    }

    // maybe its better to use a custom Repository Interface here as return type that has a "FetchAll" method
    public DBContext Get(string parameter) {
        switch(parameter) {
            case "todo":
                return this.todoContext;
           break;
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend to use this factory as a singleton instance, preferrable using the dependency injection of ASP.net (register as service)

```
[Route("table/{tableName}")]
public IEnumerable<object> GetTableByName(string tableName) { 
   return this.dbContextFactory.Get(tableName).FetchAll();
}
```

Keep in mind that the last code is only pseudocode. Be sure you only allow access to this endpoint for users who have the correct priviliges and only allow access to tables the user is allowed to access.